# No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: multithreading, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I am using LibGDX to make a game. I want to simultaneously load/unload assets on the fly as needed. However, waiting for assets to load in the main thread causes lag. In order to remedy this, I've created a **background thread** that monitors which assets need to be loaded (textures, sounds, etc.) and loads/unloads them appropriately.

Unfortunately, I get the following error when calling `AssetManager.update()` from that thread.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
```

I've tried `run`ing the background thread in the main thread in the beginning and just dealing with the first few screens, and everything works fine. I can also change the algorithm to just load everything into memory from the start in the same thread, and that works as well. However, neither works in the background thread.

When I run this on Android with OpenGL ES 2.0 (which is flexible in odd ways) instead of on Windows, everything runs fine, and I can even get the pixel dimensions of the images - **but the textures render black**.

My searches have told me that this is an issue of the **OpenGL context** being bound to a single thread, but not much else. This explains why everything works when I shove it in the main thread, and not when I put it in a different one. How do I fix this context problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First things first, you should not access the OpenGL context outside of the rendering thread.**

I assume you have looked at these already, but just to make sure read up on the [AssetManager wiki article](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager), which talks a bit about how to use the AssetManager for asynchronous managing of assets. In addition to the wiki article, check out the [AssetManagerTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/AssetManagerTest.java) to better understand how to use it. The asset manager test is probably your best bet into loading at how to dynamically load assets.

If you are loading a ton of stuff, you may want to look into creating a loading bar to load anything large upfront. It might work to check assets and such from another thread (and set a flag to call update), but at the end of the day you will need to call [update()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#update%28%29) on the rendering thread.

Keeping in mind you have to call update() it from a different thread, I don't see why you would want another thread to check conditions and set a flag. There is probably more overhead using another thread and synchronizing the update() call than to just do it all on the rendering thread. Also, the update() method only pauses for a couple milliseconds at a time as it incrementally loads files. Typically, you would simply call [load()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) for your asset, then check [isLoaded()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#isLoaded%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) on your asset. If it isn't loaded you would then call update() once per frame until isLoaded() returns true. Once it returns true, you can then call [get()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) and get whatever asset you were loading. This can all be done via the main rendering thread without having the app lag while its loading.

If you really want your other thread to call update(), you need to create a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) object and call [postRunnable()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.html#postRunnable%28java.lang.Runnable%29) such as how they have it described in the [wiki article](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationThreading) on multi-threading with libGDX. However, this defeats the whole point of using other threads because anything you use with postRunnable runs synchronously on the rendering thread.

Comment: -1 for wrongly stating OpenGL contexts couldn't be used from multiple threads. It's perfectly possible to detach a OpenGL context from one thread and attach it to another.

Comment: How is detaching and attaching a context to another thread using it in a multithreaded sense? The context itself can only be access by a single thread at a time unless you want to try and use locking to achieve it. However, that defeats the whole point.

Comment: You did claim that the OpenGL context could be used from the rendering thread only, implying that only the thread that did create the context could use it. BTW: you can create several OpenGL contexts on the same drawable with shared object namespaces and attach each to a own thread. This gives you multithreading.

Comment: I see what you are saying, it is possible and has its uses, but for this particular problem with libGDX I would not advise it. I'll update my answer.